# How to test if exactly one condition is true?

Tags: boolean, pascal

If I have a set of boolean variables in Pascal, how can I test if *exactly one* of them is `True`?

Comment: `b1 xor b2 xor b3` is also true if they're ALL true.  You should fix the question to say what you really want -- exactly one true or a 3-variable xor.  Also, you should say what language you're working in, since they have different syntactical features that might be used.

Comment: Apparently there is no easy way to do this, I learned this in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888174/how-do-i-determine-if-exactly-one-boolean-is-true-without-type-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pascal you can do this:

```
if Integer(a) + Integer(b) + Integer(c) = Integer(true) then
    writeln("exactly one is true");
```

It's important to compare to `Integer(true)`, since it could be different values in different versions of Pascal.

Comment: I got it. Because the sum can only give Integer 1 to only 1 true.

Comment: Please note that in Delphi, a boolean variable *might* (depending on how it was created) be something different from `1 = Ord(True)`. In such strange cases, it is safer to do `Ord(a <> False) + Ord(b <> False) + Ord(c <> False) = 1`. Because even if `a` happens to be `Boolean(4)`, we have `Ord(a <> False) = Ord(True) = 1`.